# Onclick asp.net event not triggered after javascript confirmation in gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, confirm

On my gridview I associate a javascript OnClick method to a linkbuton that asks to confirm the deletion of the bounded row:

```
protected void DeleteRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow grdrow = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;
        using (ShoppingCartActions usersShoppingCart = new ShoppingCartActions())
        {
            string cartId = usersShoppingCart.GetCartId();

            int rowIndex = grdrow.RowIndex;

            //int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
            string itemId = ((HiddenField)CartList.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("hiddenEncryptedItemID")).Value;
            usersShoppingCart.RemoveItemWithOptionsAndValues(cartId, itemId);
            CartList.DataBind();
            lblTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:N2}", usersShoppingCart.GetTotal());
            //return usersShoppingCart.GetCartItems();
        }
    }
```

For cosmetic reason I built my ItemTemplate this way:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <div class="divItemTotal">
       <div>
           <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="totalItem" ID="lblItemTotalPrice" Text='<%#: String.Format("{0:N2}", ((Convert.ToDouble(Item.Quantity)) *  Convert.ToDouble(Item.UnitPrice)))%>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCurrency2" Text=" €"></asp:Label></div>
            <asp:LinkButton OnClick="DeleteRow_Click" CssClass="removeItem imgRemoveItem" runat="server" ID="DeleteRow"></asp:LinkButton>
       </div>
```

In an perfect world the javascript method should prevent the page to execute the postback and let it go if confirmed. Unfortunately when clicked Ok nothing happens and the ASP.net method is never triggered. Even more weird withtout the javascript function the asp method does only fire from time to time and I still have no assumption for that.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <div class="divItemTotal">
   <div>
      <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="totalItem" ID="lblItemTotalPrice" Text='<%#: String.Format("{0:N2}", ((Convert.ToDouble(Item.Quantity)) *  Convert.ToDouble(Item.UnitPrice)))%>'></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCurrency2" Text=" €"></asp:Label></div>
      <asp:LinkButton CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Item.Id") %>' CommandName="Delete" CssClass="removeItem imgRemoveItem" runat="server" ID="DeleteRow"></asp:LinkButton>
   </div>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void CartList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{ 
LinkButton l = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("DeleteRow"); 
l.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return " +
"confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record " +
DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Item.Id") + "')");
}



protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, 
                     GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
 {
   // get the categoryID of the clicked row
  int categoryID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
  // Delete the record 
  DeleteRecordByID(categoryID);
// Implement this on your own :) 
}
}
```

Comment: Ok I moved a step forward. Both technique (yours and mine) are actually working. Only the first row gets deleted when I have more than one. I did not realize that before because I was testing with one element in grid only.